# Tridiagonal matrix power with negative diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I have a tridiagonal matrix with negative diagonal and and non-negative off-diagonal elements where every row sums to zero (it is the generator to an M/M/n/n queue). My experiments indicate that $|A|^p $ = $|A^p|$, where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value of every element, but I am not able to prove this.

Comment: @user8675309 How do you get $\exp(A)=\exp|A|$ ? Do you think it follows from $|A^p|=|A|^p$ ? It is not true for numbers.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am not sure I get your point. If $|A^p| = |A|^p$ then I guess that $exp(A) = exp|A|$.

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg $e^{-1}\neq e^{|-1|}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, generally it is not true but I am interested in the case when $A$ is the generator to an M/M/n/n queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ denote the diagonal matrix with entries $(-1)^i$ on the main diagonal, i.e.
$$d_{ij}=\begin{cases}(-1)^i & j=i\\
0 & j\neq i
\end{cases} $$ Observe
that the matrix $DAD$ has nonpositive entries and $|DAD|=|A|.$ Therefore $|A|=-DAD.$  We have $D^2=I.$ Hence $(DAD)^k=DA^kD.$ Therefore $|(DAD)^k|=|DA^kD|=|A^k|.$  Thus $$|A|^k=(-DAD)^k=(-1)^kDA^kD=|DA^kD|=|A^k|$$

**Remark** The assumption that the rows sum up to $0$ is not necessary for the conclusion.